# Save console output to file pycharm while saving previous runs?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow use the `Save console output to file` option in PyCharm while saving the output of previous runs.  I have searched but haven't found a way.  I was hoping it was possible to pass some dynamic filename based off start time so a new file is made each run or an append instead of overwrite file option, but I couldn't find either.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm, the Run console restarts each time you run your program in it.
Something that might solve your problem is running your program in the terminal (one is embedded in Pycharm), like this:

```
python3 main.py
```

Here the script `main.py` is executed like with the Run button with Pycharm.
But, as long as you don't close this terminal, you will see the previous output.